# How to pass on data from multiple sections in a UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, segue

I'm new to Swift. I'm trying to show an image in a detail view, and this image comes from a `UICollectionViewController`. My questions are:

1. How can I send the data to the detail view via segue? I can't use `if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForSelectedRow...` So what is the right way?
2. How can I tell when the user taps on images from different sections of the `UICollectionViewController` and then pass this information on to the `DetailView`?

**AudiUICollectionViewController.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class AudiUICollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

var audiPictures01:[carData] = [
                              carData(name:"01", picture:"1"),
                              carData(name:"02", picture:"2"),
                              carData(name:"03", picture:"3"),
                              carData(name:"04", picture:"4"),
                              carData(name:"05", picture:"5"),
                              carData(name:"06", picture:"6")]

var audiPictures02:[carData] = [
                              carData(name:"07", picture:"7"),
                              carData(name:"08", picture:"8"),
                              carData(name:"09", picture:"9"),
                              carData(name:"10", picture:"10"),
                              carData(name:"11", picture:"11"),
                              carData(name:"12", picture:"12")
                              ]


override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return audiPictures01.count
    } else {
        return audiPictures02.count
    }

}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AudiUICollectionViewCell

        cell.collectionPicture.image = UIImage(named: audiPictures01[indexPath.row].picture)
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AudiUICollectionViewCell

        cell.collectionPicture.image = UIImage(named: audiPictures02[indexPath.row].picture)
        return cell
    }


}

//I don't know how to set the segue to pass the data

}
```

**AudiDetailViewController.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class audiDetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var audiDetailImageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Eric, Thank you for your help to correct my poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use prepareForSegue() functionality to data between your controller from parents to it's child or another way your detailViewController, I add the prepareForSegue() to your code and it should be look like this

```
 import UIKit

 class AudiUICollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

 var audiPictures01:[carData] = [
                          carData(name:"01", picture:"1"),
                          carData(name:"02", picture:"2"),
                          carData(name:"03", picture:"3"),
                          carData(name:"04", picture:"4"),
                          carData(name:"05", picture:"5"),
                          carData(name:"06", picture:"6")]

 var audiPictures02:[carData] = [
                          carData(name:"07", picture:"7"),
                          carData(name:"08", picture:"8"),
                          carData(name:"09", picture:"9"),
                          carData(name:"10", picture:"10"),
                          carData(name:"11", picture:"11"),
                          carData(name:"12", picture:"12")
                          ]


override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
return 2
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
if section == 0 {
    return audiPictures01.count
} else {
    return audiPictures02.count
}

}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

if indexPath.section == 0 {
    let cell =          collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AudiUICollectionViewCell

    cell.collectionPicture.image = UIImage(named: audiPictures01[indexPath.row].picture)
    return cell
} else {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AudiUICollectionViewCell

    cell.collectionPicture.image = UIImage(named:       audiPictures02[indexPath.row].picture)
    return cell
}


}

//I don't know how to set the segue to pass the data
// use this line of code in your view controller

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    if let detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as? audiDetailViewController {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetailViewController" {
            let selectedRow = self.collectionView!.indexPathForCell((sender as! UICollectionViewCell))
            var category: carData?
            if selectedRow!.section == 0 {
                category = audiPictures01[selectedRow!.row]
            } else {
                category = audiPictures02[selectedRow!.row]
            }
            detailVC.name = category.name
            detailVC.picture = category.picture
        }
    }

}

}
```

and in DetailViewController you should create a var for name and picture or you can just make one variable of your own object to pass data to it.
I just create 2 var one for 'name' and the other for 'picture' and you detailController looks like this

```
import UIKit

class audiDetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var audiDetailImageView: UIImageView!
var picture: String?
var name: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
         print(name, picture)
    }
}
```

hope this will help

Comment: Hi Arash, Many thanks for your help! But I get a problem in below codes
if selectedRow!.section == 0 {
                    category = audiPictures01[selectedRow!.row]
                } else {
                    category = audiPictures02[selectedRow!.row]
                }

the error message is: Cannot assign value of type 'carData' to type '[carData]?'. Can you help me to solve it?
thanks!

Comment: the was from this line 'var category: [carData]?' change it to 'var category: carData?' and it should solve your problem

Comment: Another question is how to get the right picture in detail view when user click the picture shows in collectionView??

I'm trying to modify the code in detailViewController, but can't get any feedback. Can you give me some hits? Thanks!

@IBOutlet weak var audiDetailImageView: UIImageView!
    var picture = ""
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        audiDetailImageView.image = UIImage(named: picture)
    }

Comment: Your code correct and it should be work well unless the image name you are passing to DetailView is nil, lessen to image and make sure you getting it right. one more thing if your image store in server and you want to show that image `UIImage(named: picture)` you can't use this method to show image

Comment: It works when I clear all the code about prepareForSegue and then type again. Many thanks for your time to teach me and give me so many hints.